# Python, how do I make a countdown clock that asks the user what number they want to start at

Tags: python

Okays so I'm new to python and I just really need some help with this. This is my code so far. I keep getting a syntax error and I have no idea what im doing wrong

```
count = int(input("What number do you want the timer to start: "))
count == ">" -1:
print("count")
print("")
count = count - 1
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: If you have an error then **include** the error and specify which line the error occurs

Comment: What exactly is this line supposed to do `count == ">" -1:` ? You're checking equality of 1 substracted from a string (which you can't do).

Comment: Also, please fix the formatting of the code. Unless this is verbatim how you have your code, in which case the error is obviously (or also) about the missing indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you import the time library before you can access the time.sleep method.

Also it may be more effective to a for use a loop to repeat code. The structure of your if statement is also incorrect and is not a correct expression.

```
IF <Expression> is TRUE:
    DO THIS.
```

Also consider using a range within your for loop see below;

```
import time
count = int(input("What number do you want the timer to start: "))
for countdown in range(count,0,-1):
    print (countdown)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Explanation;

```
for countdown in range(count,0,-1):
```

range (starting point, end point, step) . Starts at your given integer, ends at 0, steps by -1 every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd line, you can't deduct 1 from ">" which is a string.
What you need here is apparently a for loop. EDIT: You forgot the import too!

```
import time
count = int(input("What number do you want the timer to start: "))
for i in range(count):
    print("count")
    print(i)
    count = count - 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error presumably comes from the line that reads

```
count == ">" -1:
```

I'm not sure where you got that from! What you need is a *loop* that stops when the counter runs out, and otherwise repeats the same code.

```
count = int(input("What number do you want the timer to start: "))
while count > 0:
    print("count", count)
    print("")
    count = count - 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

You could also replace `count  = count -1` with `count -= 1` but that won't make any difference to the operation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must `import time` in order to use the `time.sleep()` function

Next, I'm not too sure what you mean by:

> `count == ">" -1:`

If you're creating a "stopwatch", then it would be logical to use some sort of a loop:

```
while count > 0:
    print(count,"seconds left")
    count -= 1
    time.sleep(1)

print ("Finished")
```

That should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your second line. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve there. Probably you want to check if count>-1.

do this:

```
import time
count = int(input("What number do you want the timer to start: "))
if count>0:
  while(count):
    print(count)
    time.sleep(1)
    count = count -1
```